# Django getting NoReverseMatchexception

Tags: python, django

My root urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')), # new
]+static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My pages app urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
    path('<tab>', views.home,name='home'),
]
```

With this, I am able to access
127.0.0.1:8000/Home
127.0.0.1:8000/About
127.0.0.1:8000/Services
127.0.0.1:8000/Portfolio

All the tabs with  url entry.

But, when I create an url entry in html template, {% url 'About' %}
getting NoReverseMatch

Comment: where is your 'About' in url patterns?

Answer (score 0):

Very clever - I see you have 'short circuited' adding extra url patterns with your 'tab' path.

The issue is that django - specifically your templates - do not know what url 'About' refers to as you have not declared it as a name to any route in your url patterns.

i.e. something like:

```
path('/path/to/about', views.about_function, name='About')
```

What you can do in your template is hard code the path, for example:

```
<a href='/hardcode/this/path'> About </a>
```

Just note that if you change the 'About' page path, you'll need to replace it everywhere it's defined in any of your templates - plus possibly some other side effects.

Comment: without template, I am able to access the url with the <tab> pattern directly.By entering the url but with templates added I am getting this error.Any option instead of hard coding these pages.

Comment: The option is to add the route to your url patterns - use the first block of code in my answer.